# Errors with WorkItemMigrationConfig Processor

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools

We are using the Azure DevOps OSS Migration tool and we watch the video and links.

We are migrating from one Azure DevOps organization to another organization.

We constantly encounter issue like below and the migration tool is halt.

```
Error:
[16:02:15 INF] [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemLinkValidationException: TF201066: You cannot add a Child link to work item 9690 because a work item can have only one Parent link. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: TF201036: You cannot add a Child link between work items 9815 and 9690 because a work item can have only one Parent link.
```

I am using Version 10, in my configuration.json, I just useNodeStructuresMigrationConfig and WorkItemMigrationConfig processors.

```
"QueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
```

I migrate all open work items, then migrate the closed work items.  Sometimes during migrating closed work item, the migration tool would create a duplicated parents and empty work item.

Here is my configuration.json:

```
{
      "ObjectType": "MigrationTools.Core.Configuration.Processing.WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "QueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] = '' AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
      "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "Enabled": true,
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": false,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMazSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false,
      "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false
    }
```

Can someone please provide some light on the error?

Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You might misconfigured the Migration tracking field `ReflectedWorkItemId`, which caused above error. You can refer to this document to check the actual name of the `ReflectedWorkItemID` field. Check [this issue here](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/503) for more information.

For the duplicated parents issue. There has been an issue reported [here](https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/397), you can follow it up.

You can try migrating the all the work items at one time. Because in my test, If i first migrate the open work items, then migrate the closed work items. I will lost the parent and child links in the migrated closed work items.

Comment: thank you. I added ReflectedWorkItemId field to some of my work item types.

Answer (score 0):

This should be resolved as of v10.2.11 shipped on Sun at 14:30 by Gordon Beeming.

https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/452

If it is still not working then please add your information to the ticket above.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I updated the tool, but got this

You are currently running version {"Major": 0, "Minor": 0, "Build": 0, "Revision": 0, "MajorRevision": 0, "MinorRevision": 0, "$type": "Version"} and a newer version ({"Major": 11, "Minor": 2, "Build": 0, "Revision": 0, "MajorRevision": 0, "MinorRevision": 0, "$type": "Version"}) is available. You should upgrade now using Chocolatey command 'choco upgrade vsts-sync-migrator' from the command line.

Comment: actually i press Yes to continue to run and it runs! thank you!